# Is this (stochastic) integral finite?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to prove a statement and a term comes up for which I need to show that it is finite.
Let $(W_s)_{s\geq0}$ be a $\mathbb{P}$-Brownian motion. Is for any $t\geq0$ the following integral finite
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t (e^{W_s})^2 ds\right].$$

I know that using It's Isometry one can conclude 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^t (e^{W_s})^2 ds\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[(\int_0^t e^{W_s} dW_s)^2\right].$$
But I don't see how this helps me.

Comment: This doesn't help. Why bring in $dW_s$ when we have a simple integral w.r.t. Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 5):

This is an ordinary Lebesgue/Riemann  integral (of a non-negative continuous function w.r.t. Lebesgue measure).  We can apply Fubini's Theorem to evaluate it.  $\mathbb E\int_0^{t} (e^{W_s})^{2}ds=\int_0^{t}\mathbb E e^{2W_s} ds=\int_0^{t}e^{2s}ds=\frac {e^{2t}-1} 2$.